# How to convert integer as character in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, char, int, type-conversion

I have got a situation where i add character to the Observablecollection.
The value i have to add is 7 which is of integer type, now when i add it like this:

```
ObservableCollection<char> numbersList = new ObservableCollection<char>(word);
char Xis = Convert.ToChar(11 - returnModeofEleven(sum));
numbersList.Add(Xis);
Console.WriteLine("char is :" + Convert.ToChar(Xis));
```

Now nothing is printed on console for Convert.ToChar(Xis) , i want to print **7** as value i got from `Convert.ToChar(11 - returnModeofEleven(sum));` is of int type and it's 7.

How to transform this int to char such that my console will print

```
 char is : 7
```

instead of (empty)

```
char :
```

On debugging when i see the value at the position where i have added in numbersList then i get `numbersList [8] = 7 '\a'` , so it while converting int (7) to char Convert() converts it to '\a'(which is 7 of ascii) but i do not want it.I want to convert int of 7 to 7 of char and get saved in my observable collection.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("char is :" + Xis);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers does not start from 0 in ASCII characters. they start from 48. Add value to `'0'` to get the correct char.

```
Console.WriteLine("char is :" + (char)('0' + Xis));
```

Or simply cast `Xis` to int.

```
 Console.WriteLine("char is :" + (int)Xis);
```